# Installing VIM plugins to a central location and making them globally available to all users

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I've installed syntastic VIM plugin by following instructions from the plugin docs via pathogen.

1. Install pathogen:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
   curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
   ```
2. Install syntastic as pathogen bundle:

   ```
   cd ~/.vim/bundle &&
   git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic.git
   ```

At this point it's in my `$HOME/.vim` directory of my Linux user.

I'd like to install this plugin to be globally available for all users on the box, but I'm having trouble finding out how to go about doing it. All the instructions seem to talk about installing plugins under `$HOME/.vim`.

Comment: Is that a sysadmin issue (single box/image shared by many human users) or the classic XY problem of "I would like to have the same plugins whether I use Vim as root or as a normal user"?

Comment: @romainl, it's the sysadmin issue... That made me think, does this question belong here on stackoverflow? Or should I ask it on a diff site?

Comment: Try installing all plugins in e.g. `/usr/local/share/vim/bundle` and making `~/.vim/bundle` a symbolic link to that.

Comment: If you use the vim-plug plugin manager, you can specify where it should install plugins.

Comment: Read the docs for pathogen.  You can specify a list of directories in `pathogen#infect()`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, please add this as answer.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/1612035 has an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

#### Recommended

- Before you start, update your vim to the last version. If using `debian`, install `vim.nox` (python support) and run `update-alternatives` for `vim`, `vi` and `vimdiff`.

#### How-to

Using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) I've managed to create a global plugin installation.

This is a step-by-step explanation;

1. create `/etc/vim/autoload`. Make sure others can read/execute the directory.
2. add `plug.vim` file in it. Make sure all users can read it. See below: Download
3. add to (preferred the begin of) your `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`

   ```
   set runtimepath+=/etc/vim/autoload
   " Initialize plugin system
   call plug#begin('/etc/vim/plugged')
   " Vimtemplates - templates for diverse files
   Plug 'drbeco/vimtemplates', { 'do': '/etc/vim/plugged/vppinstall.sh' }
   " VimColors8 - colorschemes for all
   Plug 'drbeco/vimcolors8', { 'do': '/etc/vim/plugged/vppinstall.sh' }
   call plug#end()
   " End of initialization of plugin system
   ```

The two plugins (repositories) above, namely `drbeco/vimtemplates` and `drbeco/vimcolors8` are optional and are there just to test the installation. You need some plugin there to run `:PlugInstall` and this two are small, easy and compatible. Feel free to change, but I recommend you first install all, check if it is ok, then change all `vim-plug` session to your taste.

4. Create a directory `/etc/vim/plugged/`. Make sure all users can read/execute it.

Add the following script to the `plugged` directory (make it executable):

**$ cat /etc/vim/plugged/vppinstall.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# notice
echo "vppinstall.sh (C) 2017 Dr. Beco: Correcting plugin's permissions"

# work in plugged directory
cd /etc/vim/plugged

# execute (open) and read directories
find . -type d ! -wholename "*/.git*" -exec chmod o+rx {} \;

# read all files
find . -type f ! -wholename "*/.git*" -exec chmod o+r {} \;
```

This script will run as post-installation hook to correct the permissions of the files. You can set *stick-bits* or redefine your *UMASK* instead of running this script, but unless you know the security risks I don't recommend.

Almost done.

5. Reload .vimrc and run :PlugInstall to install plugins.
   For each new plugin you add to your `vimrc.local`, make sure it calls the post-installation script, or else users won't be able to use them.

--

#### Download

To download the `plug.vim` file, use:

```
curl -fLo /etc/vim/autoload/plug.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Comment: Note: I'm still debugging some minor problems with this answer. The issue is at github original vim-plug repo. If you know how to solve them, you are welcome to join. I'll update my answer when it is all worked out. Here the link to the issue: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/657